# Dynamics CRM: More than one cascading relationship between two entities?

Tags: dynamics-crm

In Dynamics CRM Online, I have an entity "Account" and an Entity "Order Confirmation". Account can be related to the Confirmation by the following fields: Confirmation as Invoice Recipient OR Confirmation as Customer (Because an order can be sent to one customer, while another company recieves the invoice).

If the account is shared with a team / user, this user has to not only see the account, but also the account's order confirmations, but BOTH as invoice recipient AND customer.

Dynamics CRM allows me to configure only one cascading relationship between two entities, which has the effect, that after a share, the other user can only see either confirmations as invoice recipient OR confirmations as customer.

How can I work around this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way to solve your issue is usage of plugins/workflows.